# Android Studio is not showing the file -> new -> new module option as instructed for the Spotify SDK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, spotify

I am developing a flutter app, and would like to use this Spotify package to connect to the phone's Spotify app through my app (similar to how Google Maps does, or Waze): https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk

Within that site, instruction 2 under Android Setup states:

> download the current Spotify Android SDK. Here you need the spotify-app-remote-.aar >and spotify-auth-.aar.
> After you are all setup you need to add the *.aar files to your Android Project as >Modules. See the Spotify Android SDK Quick Start for detailed information.

> Important here is the naming so that the package can find the modules.

```
Remote: spotify-app-remote
Auth: spotify-auth
```

The Spotify Android QuickStart guide they refer to https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/ states:

> Add the App Remote SDK
>
> Unzip the App Remote SDK zip file that you downloaded. Add the library to your project >by importing it as a module. In the “Project” side bar in Android Studio (View –> Tool >Windows –> Project), right click your project’s root folder and navigate to “New” –> >“Module”.
>
> In the “New Module” window, choose the option “Import .JAR/AAR Package”. Click “Next”.
>
> Press the “…” button and locate the spotify-app-remote-release-version.aar under the >“app-remote-lib” folder in the unzipped bundle. Click “Open” and choose a suitable >subproject name. We’re using spotify-app-remote in this example. Click “Finish” to >import the .aar into your project.
>
> Add a dependency on the spotify-app-remote module to your app by adding the imported >subproject and Gson to your app’s build.gradle file. It is important that the name >that you specify in the build.gradle file is the same as the subproject name you >decided on.

However, nowhere in Android Studio can I find that I can right click and have an option New->Module.  In the File menu, I can select File->New->"Import Module", but that does not give me the option to import the .aar module.  I also see no .gson in anything unzipped from Spotify.

Also, this only instructs on what to do with the remote module, but the flutter package's instructions also talk about the auth module.  With regards to the auth module, there is this site from Spotify: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/ which states:

> Copy the spotify-auth-version.aar file into the /app/libs directory in your project’s >root directory.
>
> In Android Studio, edit the build.gradle file in the app directory (it can also be >labelled as Module: app) and make sure it contains the dependency on the library:

And my flutter app in AndroidStudio does not have an app/libs folder either.

So altogether this is quite confusing, and I'd be thankful if someone could provide clearer instructions on how to setup the use of Spotify integration in Flutter.

Thank you.